# How to change the slider value automatically when the number of images change?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two sets of images (`set1: 100 images`; `set2: 25 images`).
Initially I use `popupmenu` to select `set1` of 100 images and use `slider` to view them.
Let's say my `slider value` at a point is `56`.

Now, if I use the `popupmenu` to select `set2` of `25 images`.
`as the slider value is 56 (> max: 25), the slider  control is disappearing`.

```
Warning: 'slider' control cannot have a 'Value' outside of 'Min'-'Max' range
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid
```

Is there any way to reset the slider based on my `popmenu` selection.

I used a `flag` to get `popmenu selection` to `slider_callback`

```
if popmenu _FLG == 0 % set-1 images (100)
    maxNumberOfImages= length(IMGS);
    set(hObject, 'Min', 0);
    set(hObject, 'Max', maxNumberOfImages);
    % set(handles.sliderC, 'Value', 1);
    set(hObject, 'SliderStep', [1/maxNumberOfImages , 10/maxNumberOfImages ]);

elseif popmenu  == 1 % set-2 images (25)
    maxNumberOfImages= length(SERIES_IMGS);
    set(hObject, 'Min', 0);
    set(hObject, 'Max', maxNumberOfImages);
    % set(handles.sliderC, 'Value', 1);
    set(hObject, 'SliderStep', [1/maxNumberOfImages , 10/maxNumberOfImages ]);

end
```

Now when i use get to obtain value it is greater than 25 too:

```
value = int32(get(hObject,'Value'));
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out this, posting in case someone else has a similar issue:

```
value = int32(get(hObject,'Value'));
if value == 0 || maxNumberOfImages == 1 
    value = 1;
elseif value > maxNumberOfImages
    value = maxNumberOfImages;
end
disp(value);
set(handles.sliderC, 'Value', value);
```

In case if the value is greater than `maxNumberOfImages`, I am setting the current `handle value` to the `maxNumberOfImages` again which resets the slider controls as I expected without disabling the slider.